# Play Video Instantly (like YouTube) on HTML after URL has been saved in mysql Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, video

I have made a small html website which uploads your video onto my website,  by saving the video reference in mySQL and displaying all files in the database on a website, I have done this successfully, but I am not able to play videos in realtime like YouTube, i need to download the video aand view it on my own desktop player... I wish to in a way stream the URl from the database playing on the website ... if that makes sense!

Thank you fellow Community Members.

Answer (score 0):

Provide some more data please. Like what path do you use, etc.